# Add extra div under each row of table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MVC 4 application where one of my view appears something like:

[image]

and the corresponding code for this view is:

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <tr id="document-row-@item.DocumentId">
           <td>                        
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentName)
                 <div id="document-detail-contentsREVW">

                 </div>
           </td>

           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                  <div class="pull-right"> 
                           @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "DocumentDetail", "Documents", new { Area = "SmartDocs", id = item.DocumentId.ToString() , currentStatus = item.CurrentStatus.ToString()}, new AjaxOptions
                        {
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                           HttpMethod = "GET",
                           LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
                           UpdateTargetId = "document-detail-contentsREVW",
                        }, new { @class = "details-link" })

                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

Now once I click on the Details link ,one controller action method is called and the details for that record is displayed just beneath the first row in a tabular format inside a **document-detail-contentsREVW** as used in my view and can be seen as:

[image]

which is the details for the first record.Now again if I click on the details for the 3rd or any of the other record the position for showing the detail is the same as shown in the below view :
[image]

Here , I want the details to be shown just below that particular record for which the link has been clicked.Functionality is working fine here.Also on click of details I am able to **toggle**(hide/unhide) the details div.

I feel that the position for using my div inside a tr is wrong and hence everytime the same place gets refreshed on details click.

I searched regarding this a lot and even found lot of fiddles to achieve this.For ex:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/30/**(I want something like this)

But here the details are prewritten and are used on click of the icon.But in my case , I will be getting the details dynamically after the click of the details link for that record.I guess I am clear with my requirement.
So, can this be done by jquery or how can I achieve this..?
Thanks in advance.

Following is my script:

```
   $(function () {
        $('.details-link').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.document-details').toggle();
            $(this).text(function (i, v) {
                return v === 'Details' ? 'Hide' : 'Details';
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that you have given all your `<div>` elements the same ID (which is invalid html). The `Ajax.ActionLink` is finding the first matching ID and replacing its contents. You will need to generate unique ID's in you loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do I need to do this with jquery under ready function or can you please tell me in more details regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have given all your  elements the same ID. Apart from being invalid html, the `@Ajax.ActionLink()` method is updating the first element with `id=document-detail-contentsREVW` (not necessarily the one in the corresponding row). You need to create unique ID's in you loop.  If your model is `IList` then you can use (for example);

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  var id = string.Format("document-detail-{0}", i);
  <tr id="document-row-@item.DocumentId">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DocumentName)
    <div id=@id></div> // id will be "document-detail-0", "document-detail-1" etc
    ....
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Details",.....
    {
      ....
      UpdateTargetId = @id,
```

If you model is `IEnumerable`, declare a counter before the loop, and increment the counter in the `foreach` statement

```
@{int i = 0;} // declare counter
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  var id = string.Format("document-detail-{0}", i++);
  <tr id="document-row-@item.DocumentId">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DocumentName) // same as before
    <div id=@id></div>
    ....
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Details",.....
      ....
      UpdateTargetId = @id,
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but m a bit of confused over here since mine is Ienumerable,I tried with declaring a counter outside the foreach loop and integrating with your answer but again I am getting error at **m => m[i].DocumentName**.Can you please look into this issue.

Comment: That worked super.Thanks for that .Now also if u see my question the id **document-detail-contentsREVW** I have used in script to toggle the div part with live (click function).So, now since the div no more exist with that name,how to use that div's id in script?

Comment: First, DO NOT USE `.live()`, it was depreciated in jquery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 (use `.on()` instead).  You haven't posted you script so can't give detailed solution, but suggest you give the `<div>` a class name as well (say "document-details"), then in the `.click()` event, select the corresponding `<div>` e.g. `$(this).closest('tr').find('.document-details').toggle();`

Comment: Thanks again..removed the live and used **on** instead in my script.Followed you and it is working really great.Thanks a lot Stephen.

Comment: @Saroj, My suggestion above toggles the visibility. The initial state of the `<div>` is visible, so the first click hides it. In the document ready function, initially set the state of all `<div>` to hidden using `$('.document-details').hide();`.

Comment: Yup.That worked too..Thanks for all the help.Thanks a lot Stephen.

Comment: Hi Stephen,need your help again.Here,**UpdateTargetId = @id**,in this part , the id will be dynamic everytime isnt it.Now my problem is that this div I need to update in some other page as well where I'm using ajax.actionlink again,and there in UpdateTargetId ,I need to pass this id.Since it is dynamic all the time,I'm sort of confused,how to do this.Can this be done using class..?

Comment: AFAIK, not cant use a class name. I don't really understand what you mean - its just a mater of constructing a unique id (in this case I did it in  the for loop by using the value of `i`). If you want more flexibility, dump `@Ajax.ActionLink` (its obsolete as far as I'm concerned) and use jquery's `$.get()` or `$.load()` methods